# Is it possible to specify interfaces for a reverse tunnel in PuTTY?

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop, putty

I am trying to set up a reverse tunnel from a Windows 7 box (call it A) behind a firewall to a DD-WRT router on my home network (call this B). The situation is this, I would like to be able to RDP into box A, and for security the admin does not want to forward ports (I wouldn't either!) but I am unable to connect to the VPN (long story, the VPN server does not play well with the available Linux VPN clients), so I thought of the possibility of using a reverse tunnel to accomplish this. I have been able to connect to box B using PuTTY, so no problem there, but I would like to be able to initiate the RDP connection from my laptop since box B is a just a router. I have not been able to determine how to tell it to listen on an interface other than localhost.

Is there a way to specify the interface in PuTTY similar to doing

```
ssh -f -N -R 192.168.1.2:9999:localhost:3389 me@boxB
```

which makes boxB listen on its local IP address (in this example 192.168.1.2) instead of localhost? Or should I just let it listen on all interfaces (I assume this is what the "Local ports accept connections from other hosts" and "Remote ports do the same" options in PuTTY do) and set up some iptables rules on box B to drop packets from outside the local network on that port?